# Minimum number of tickets to bet in a lottery to win a prize

Tags: combinatorics

I use the formula wins = C(m-a, p-k) * C(a, k) [see Note below], to calculate the number of winning cards in Mega-sena, a 6/60 lottery managed by state bank CEF/Brazil, that pays prizes for 6, 5 and 4 hits. The formula was tested to m values in the range 6 to 20. About this formula, I have two questions:

1. Is it generic or does it apply only to this particular case?
2. Having chosen M numbers, let's say 15, I want to know what the minimum amount of cards of 6 numbers must be played, to guarantee me at least one prize of 4 or 5 hits. Knowing that surrounding 15 numbers with C(15,6) tickets, I guarantee 55 prizes on the 4 (or 10 on the 5), can I apply the following relation to solve this problem?

minTickets = ceil (C(m, 6) / (C(m-a, p-k) * C(a, k)))

Note:
winsX = C(m-a, p-k) * C(a, k) [only if: m-a >= p-k]
where:

- winsX: number of winning tickets
- C(a, b): binomial of (a, b)
- m: total of "lucky" numbers to play (surround)
- p: number of dozens drawn (6 per mega-sena)
- a: total numbers of hits in set m
- k: premiums paid (six=6, five=5, four=4)

Golang program that print the prize table of Mega-sena:

- https://github.com/noald/go-fyne-intro/blob/main/megasena/tab-cef.go

Example: m = 15, p=6
totalTicksToBet = C(15,6) = 5005 tickets

- To guarantee at least one 5 premium: a=5, k=5
  wins5 = C(15-5, 6-5) * C(5,5) = 10 tickets
  minTickets = ceil(5005/10) = 501 tickets
- To guarantee at least one 4 premium: a=4, k=4
  wins4 = C(15-4, 6-4) * C(4,4) = 55 tickets
  minTickets = ceil(5005/55) = 91 tickets

I have only a basic math knowledge and I don't speak English, so my apologies if I didn't make myself understood. Thanks.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).